# Storageformat for audiobooks

Tags: software, playback, audiobook

So, I want to apologize in advance if this is not the right place for this question, but it was the most appropriate SE-site I could find (possibly apart from SuperUser).

I have acquired quite a few audiobooks through the years and though some are in MP3-format, some are in audio-cd format. I really want to get those audio-cd format books over to a digital format that lends itself nicely to play on my (Android) phone so that I can bring them with me.

I haven't found any good guides on how to do this. I know how to rip normal music CD's, but transferring a 20-CD audiobook with 10-20 tracks each to one file per chapter/track results in hundreds of single files. Even if I rip with cue-sheets and keep just 1 file per CD, I still end up with 20-files, and I loose the chapter overview. (At least I haven't found any players that can use CUE-sheets as chapter-guides)

So, is there any better file format for audiobooks ripped from audio CD's, or am I stuck with handling 400 files per book?